# What will be the order of select statement by default

Tags: sql-server-2008

If I insert a set of Row in a table variable . After that I `select * from table` in which order it will give me output .is it will be order of insertion of will it change

```
    DECLARE @next_seq_val NCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    seq NCHAR(50)
    )
    EXEC    [dbo].[ix_NextSeq]
        @seq_id = 58,
        @next_seq_val = @next_seq_val OUTPUT
   insert into @tbl(seq) values(@next_seq_val)
   SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

Rows in a table are not sorted. There is no "default" order. The database is free to return them in any order it finds most efficient.

Think of rows in a table like balls in a basket, they don't have an order either.

The **only** (really!) way to ensure a consistent order is to use `ORDER BY`

Comment: I wants to get Rows in order in which I have insert

Comment: @JitenderMahlawat: the only way to guarantee that is to add a column that stores the date/time when the row was inserted. Then order by that column when retrieving the row.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  May be it will will be posible by adding a column of index with identity and then select with order by index

Comment: @JitenderMahlawat: anything that is guaranteed to increment over time will do.

Answer (score 0):

It should be considered as random order. It depends on the database server.